# AspectJ joinpoint and thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety, aspectj

I have an AspectJ pointcut, given below, on method execution, when that method is invoked I am reading the arguments and validate it. The class in which the method is declared is *Singleton*. My question is will **joinPoint.getThis()** and **joinPoint.getArgs()** be thread safe.

```
@Before("atExecution() && customPointcut(customAnnotation)")
public void validate(JoinPoint joinPoint, CustomAnnotation customAnnotation)  {

    MethodSignature sig = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method =  sig.getMethod();

    ExecutableValidator execValidator = validator.forExecutables();

    //is this code thread safe?
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations= execValidator.validateParameters(joinPoint.getThis(), method, joinPoint.getArgs());

}
```